# Mysql Multiple Table query statement

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows

```
Ads Table
user_id ad_id   title             message   repost_days_id   repost_times_id
   1      1     Message Title 1   Message   1                1
   1      1     Message Title 2   Message   0                0

Repost Days Table:
repost_days_id   Value
1                5

Repost Times Table:
Repost_times_id   value
1                 10
```

Now I want to query the ads table to show ads with the ads title ads message repost days and repost times. For example it for ad 1 it will be

```
Message Title 1
Message Repost Days=10
Repost Times=5.
```

How do I write the sql statement for that? This is what I have done and is not displaying any result.

```
$q = "
select
    a.ad_id,
    a.title,
    a.message,
    rt.value,
    rd.value,
from
    ad_repost_times rt,
    ad_repost_days rd, 
    ads a 
where
    a.user_id='{$_SESSION['user_id']}' 
and rt.repost_times_id=a.repost_times_id 
and rd.repost_days_id=a.repost_days_id
";
```

Comment: You can find that in the Repost Days and Repost times table, there is no id value of 0. but in the ads table, both the repost_days_id and repost_times_id has been set to a default value of 0. Do you think this will affect the query.

Answer (score 1):

The query can't satisfy the `a.user_id='{$_SESSION['user_id']}'` condition because you have no `user_id` field in the `ads` table.

Comment: I ommited the user_id field. It is there in the table

Answer (score 1):

1. It appears that you have an extra comma at the end of the field list. This would cause a problem executing your query in the first place. Make sure you're checking for errors after you try to run the query that would alert you to the problem.
2. Your `a.user_id='{$_SESSION['user_id']}'` means there will be braces around your user id when you submit it in the SQL query. If `$_SESSION['user_id']` holds the integer 1234, then your query will look like `a.user_id='{1234}'`. (Note that this "error" may not actually be the cause of your problem if you made the same error all over your code.)
3. The following isn't a direct cause of your problem, but it's important for security reasons, and it would have avoided the problem in #2: you *need* to remove the variable substitution `a.user_id='{$_SESSION['user_id']}'`, and change it a parameter binding with `a.user_id=?` in order to avoid an SQL injection attack (and also coincidentally eliminate the typo causing issue #2).
4. To handle the default value of zero in the `repost_days_id`, `repost_times_id` you need to use a `LEFT JOIN`, like so:

   ```
   $q = "
   select
       a.ad_id,
       a.title,
       a.message,
       rt.value,
       rd.value
   from
       ads a
       LEFT JOIN ad_repost_times rt ON rt.repost_times_id=a.repost_times_id
       LEFT JOIN ad_repost_days rd ON rd.repost_days_id=a.repost_days_id
   where
       a.user_id='{$_SESSION['user_id']}' 
   ";
   ```

   The results for `rt.value` and `rd.value` will be null for rows that have 0's for the id.

   Note that I have reordered the tables (`ads a` needs to come first, otherwise you need to use `RIGHT JOIN` in certain places instead of `LEFT JOIN`), and that there should no longer be a comma between the table names. (`LEFT JOIN` *replaces* the comma).

Comment: Hello Ken, Thanks for the feedback. I have removed the extra comma on the last field query and it is showing out results now. However, It is not showing the results from the table where both the repost_days_id and repost_times_id has been set to a default value of 0. Since there is no 0 value in the respective repost days and repost times table. How do i work around this. I don't want to add 0  to those tables.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your explanations really helped me.How do i implement this "you need to remove the variable substitution a.user_id='{$_SESSION['user_id']}', and change it a parameter binding with a.user_id=?"

Comment: You have to use MySQLi, and then you use the [mysqli_stmt_bind_param](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Is this query executed without any errors?

From your table structure it seems that Ads table does not have field `user_id` and you are querying on it